# Is it possible to make a sound barrier using an ultrasonic speaker?

Tags: acoustics

Would audible sound be blocked by a wall of ultrasonic sound (see diagram below)? Since the ultrasonic speaker gives rise to fast vibrations of the air, would the audible sound still pass through it? When the audible sound passes through the ultrasonic waves, it might combine with the ultrasonic waves, generating many other frequencies. I might ask a stupid question because I don't have deep knowledge of the relevant field. I apologize for this first.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE. Although not necessary, it would be a good idea to attach a diagram with the geometry of your problem. In the linearised case (which most probably is the majority of the problems in acoustics), the ultrasound will not be able to block sound in the audible band. Unless I’m missing something fundamental here, this is not going to work (at least not in a practical manner). On the contrary, there has been some work done on creating sound barriers with *Active Noise Control* technology. It is not very practical but was researched nevertheless. You can have (cont.)

Comment: (cont.’ed) a look at this paper: *”A preliminary experimental study on virtual sound barrier system”* by Haishan Zou, Xiaojun Qiu, Jing Lu and Feng Niu ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X07004543) to the article, unfortunately not freely available).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will read the recommended documents and study them.

Comment: I've read the documents you recommended.I know about anc, but I heard it's hard to reality.Is it impossible to stop noise by using Super Directional Loudspeaker?  I attached the picture.Is it a different noise from phase difference?

Comment: What you depict is the superposition of two sound sources (perpendicularly oriented in a sense). What you want to achieve with those is for the “super directional” one to create a pressure release boundary along its main axis for the propagation of the disturbing noise. I believe that, with “conventional” methods, all you can achieve is just cancellation at one point (or rather a reduction in some area/volume) but away from it you won’t be able to control the noise field. For the “pressure release” boundary to work for the whole (spatial) domain of interest the sources should (cont.)

Comment: produce plane waves in the same direction, so that they can be matched throughout the domain. This is effectively what many one-dimensional active noise control systems do (they find applications in ducts and pipes mainly). Alternatively, you’d have to resort to sound field control methods approximating the Huygens-Fresnel principle (which practically means using the Wave Field Synthesis principle to control sound fields). But this kind of systems are kind of impractical due to the high hardware complexity they require.